# Why is opera animation so slow?

Tags: jquery, performance, animation, opera

It seems as though opera doesn't play nice with multiple animations going on simultaneously, check out [this theme](http://themes.ibrogram.com/beta/) I'm building. I've made a preloader which scatters the images outside body in random places then animates each of them into place in intervals of 0.1 seconds with the animation taking 0.8 seconds.

Here's the function I made:

```
function ea_preload_scatter() {

    if(item.length) {

        var scatter = $(window).height() + $(window).width();

        item.addClass('loading').each(function() {

            var positionX = ['','-'],
                positionY = ['','-'],
                x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2),
                y = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

            if(positionX[x] === '-') {
                posX = -scatter;
            } else {
                posX = scatter;
            }

            if(positionY[y] === '-') {
                posY = -scatter;
            } else {
                posY = scatter;
            }                

            $('img', this).addClass('absolute').css('top',posX).css('left',posY);

        });

        $(window).load(function() {

            var i = 0,
                speed = 800;

            function ea_scatter_animate(e) {

                $('img',item.eq(e)).css({
                    zIndex: '10000'+e
                }).stop().animate({
                    top:0,
                    left:0
                }, speed, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
                    $(this)
                        .removeClass('absolute')
                        .removeAttr('style')
                        .parent()
                        .removeClass('loading');
                });

                var t = setTimeout(function() {
                    if(e == item.length) {
                        clearTimeout(t);
                    } else {
                        ea_scatter_animate(i++);
                    }
                }, 100);

            }

            ea_scatter_animate(i);

        });

    }

}
```

Opera:

```
Version
11.51

Build
1087
```

Mac:

```
Platform
Mac OS X

System
10.6.8

Processor 
2.93 GHz Intel Core i7

Memory 
8GB 1333 MHz DDR3
```

So is there anything I can do to make this play nicely with Opera? Or is it just Opera being Opera?

Comment: seems like a bug of jQuery animate. try launching them one at a time maybe ? // or replace jQ.animate with css transitions. ( your page does not work in IE9, btw )

Comment: I'll get to major cross-browsing later, it's early development lol. Thanks for letting me know though! I'll give it a shot with 1 at a time.

Comment: @Brogrammer, you already have a cross-browser problem; I wouldn't defer it any more. :)

Comment: had some fun with your code... it looks like you have ran into forced reflow bug. Which means that when you are changing attributes on absolute positioned elements that are descendants of FLOATED elements - you trigger reflow all the way up in tree.