# Opera doesn't freeze table when hiding rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, cross-browser, opera

Consider following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/nzzzH/

Try to click on the div in Chrome, IE, Firefox and then compare with Opera

You can notice, that in first all < tr > elements are hidden all together, but it Opera one by one.

Which behavior is correct one, according to specs?
How could force Opera to act like other browsers?

Code:

```
<div> click </div>

<table>
  <tr><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr><td>e</td></tr>
</table>


var sleep = function (ms) {
    var unixtime_ms = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < unixtime_ms + ms) {}
}

$('div').click(function(){
    $('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        sleep(200);
    })
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to hide ~500 rows in table, and after that i need to change coloring of visible rows. In Chrome everything is done in one step, but in Opera I see the whole process.

Comment: What about [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)?

Comment: sleep() here is just to show the difference of behavior

Comment: I created a better example, your sleep-function is confusing about the sense of your question: http://jsfiddle.net/nzzzH/4/

Comment: @Simon, looks good, and yes this is what I am concerned about

Comment: Per spec, nothing is right. You can redraw whenever.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to hide rows and apply some style to visible rows, why don't you do hide them in one step?

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('tr.rows-to-hide').hide();
    $('tr:not(.rows-to-hide)').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

**EDIT**
I did three examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/nzzzH/8/ -> `.hide()` in `each()`-loop

http://jsfiddle.net/nzzzH/10/ -> `.hide()` at once

http://jsfiddle.net/nzzzH/10/ -> `.css('display', 'none')` in `each()`-loop

So indeed the use of `.hide()` in `each()`-loop is by far the slowest, unfortunately I wasn't able to find out the specific reason for this behaviour, my guess is that opera has a perfomance when working with lots of jQuery animations. My hint is to use `.hide()` at once.

**EDIT 2**
I think my guess is correct: [Why is opera animation so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460942/why-is-opera-animation-so-slow)

Comment: I have almost this code, but on large tables in Opera I can see how rows are hidden one by one, and the sample demonstrates it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace .hide() with .css({'display':'none'}) :

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    })
})
```

Comment: There's absolutely no need for an `each`-loop.

Comment: Yes, "each" loop is redundant. I just tried to keep inessential lines as is. As for replacing hide with css method - it works in Opera. Hides all rows at once. Without "animation" effect.